Failed to install UEFI dbx firmware
When trying to update firmware for the "UEFI dbx" as shown here:


I always get a "failed to update firmware!" message, as shown below:

It sais that "user needs to do an action to complete the update" but it is not clear what the action is supposed to be. Rebooting does nothing to change this.
